# Android: AVD manager won't detect Byond B54 and Micromax phones as Virtual Device

Tags: android, android-emulator, eclipse-adt, android-virtual-device

I need to use my phone as emulator/target/virtual device when I run my application. I have enabled the USB Debugging in Settings.

What more do I need to do to make Eclipse AVD Manager to detect my Byond B54 and Micromax devices? How to get in usb drivers for these devices?

Comment: You need device driver of this devices. You can download it from its respective website if available...

Comment: How to get respective websites?Is there any accepted usb driver for all devices?

Comment: Go to micromax and byond website and search for drivers..

Comment: I just answered a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22996790/eclipse-adt-wont-detect-android-devices/24170201#24170201) Give it a try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the drivers for windows to detect those devices.

if the drivers for those devices from respective manufactures are not available, 
you can download and use [moborobo](http://www.moborobo.com/products/moborobo.html). It works for most devices. I have used it for Byond tablet.

Answer (score 1):

This [Link](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html) will help you with the list of all the companies and their links which provide USB drivers. Please note that some companies may not be listed in this list. In that case you may have to go to the respective website of the company and search for the particular device driver.

As you are saying that you have enabled the `USB debugging` mode in those devices. Check whether they are connected properly. open the command prompt and type:

> adb devices

The result will give the list of the connected devices. If the device can be seen in the list then you can be sure that its connected properly. And you can install the app directly on the device by typing in:

> adb install path_of_the_apk_file/your_apk_file.apk

But note that you can only install the app in this manner not debug it.

Answer (score 0):

install pda.net on your system.this software mostly works with all devices.Search PDA.net on google and install it after downloading .