# Eclipse doesn't recognize my android device, why?

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm trying to use android sdk and eclipse on Ubuntu 12.04. It sees my device, but doesn't recognize. What could be the problem?

The error looks like this:
[image]

Comment: Check this answer of mine: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16140304/1567588

Comment: I use linux, and that solution is for WIndows. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From ..  http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html

If you're developing on Ubuntu Linux, you need to add a udev rules file that  contains a USB configuration for each type of device you want to use for development. In the rules file, each device manufacturer is identified by a unique vendor ID, as specified by the ATTR{idVendor} property. For a list of vendor IDs, see USB Vendor IDs, below. To set up device detection on Ubuntu Linux:

```
Log in as root and create this file: /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules.

Use this format to add each vendor to the file:
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0bb4", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"

In this example, the vendor ID is for HTC. The MODE assignment specifies read/write permissions, and GROUP defines which Unix group owns the device node.

Note: The rule syntax may vary slightly depending on your environment. Consult the udev documentation for your system as needed. For an overview of rule syntax, see this guide to writing udev rules.
Now execute:
chmod a+r /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules
```

Comment: I've already created that file for my ZTE. That's why I have no idea how should I solve the error.

Answer (score 1):

Have you enabled USB debugging?

Other common issue could be that you haven't installed the USB driver for your phone.

Comment: I enabled, yes. And as I know I don't have to install usb driver on linux.

Answer (score 1):

Some phones have two USB modes: mass storage mode (in which the SD card is disconnected from the phone and appears for the computer as a flash drive) and media transfer mode (in which the phone acts as an intermediary - it's slower, but your apps can still use the SD card). This setting is unrelated to the USB debugging option.

Your computer may not be able to connect to your phone to transfer apps if it's in mass storage mode. I (with a Sony XPeria M) can only use it like this in media transfer mode.

On my phone you can change this in Settings > XPeria Connectivity > USB transfer mode. I don't know if non-XPeria phones have the same options.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see your image thanks to a corporate firewall. However, there are 'usual suspects' when it comes to eclipse. In this case, reinstall android USB device drivers from the SDK.

Use the Eclipse SDK snap in to do it.

Comment: As I know, I don't have to install USB driver for my device if I'm on linux. Is it correct?

Answer (score 0):

can you run your app on this device? I think this problem is caused by the lack of some character set like Chinese. If you cannot run your app try some other tools to connect your device or show mode detail.

Comment: I've already used the same device and IDE, but on Windows 7. :)

Answer (score 0):

Some Local devices have No USB vendorId. In such a case, you cannot connect it directly, you can run it by sending apk file through mail or something like that. Devices listed in 
http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html
 has only USB venderId. Or try to find it in device's website.

Comment: I use a ZTE skate phone. And I've already successfully used it with eclipse on win7. I guess that't not the problem