# Eclipse ADT won't detect android devices

Tags: android, eclipse, adb, adt

I've done everithing I need to in order to ADB recognize my device

As you can see, it is connected.

[image]

But eclipse won't let me work in peace

[image]

Additional info:

```
juan@juan-TE5:~$ lsusb 
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 22b8:2d66 Motorola PCS 

juan@juan-TE5:~$ cat /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules
UBSYSTEM=="usb", SYSFS{idVendor}=="22b8", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="04e8", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
```

I have also checked in the device "debuggable mode".

Any ideas?

Updated

Now I see this

[image]

Comment: Have you enabled "Developer Options" on the device?

Comment: What's the API min/max setting for your app? Also, I'm sure you did but just in case, did you turn on USB debugging mode in Developer options?

Comment: okay sometimes or most times you need to set it to camera when plugging into usb as the other mode is sdcard for when you just copy files form desktop to sdcard or vice versa..understand?

Comment: yes I do, I'll give a try

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes there is another option inside of Dev Options called USB Debuggable. Need to have that on as well...as Isabel suggested.

Comment: Yes, it has an option called  USB Debuggable, and it is checked

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue on Ubuntu 14 with OpenCv 2.4.9, I found a solution.

Check out this link for more info:
http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html

Basically, all you should need to do is:

1. Create this file as sudo

   sudo nano /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules
2. Copy and paste this line, but check and make sure you have the right vendor ID, into the file:

   SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0bb4", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
3. Finally, use chmod to give permissions:

   chmod a+r /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules

You can get the vendorid from the link, it should have all of them. The mode, specifies read/write/etc. and the group defines which Unix group owns the device node.

Comment: To Follow up, I just tested with a range of newer devices with different hardware manufacturers all running android 4.2 and up and they worked fine without needed to modify the file. At least for me. I only have HTC as an entry in my file and a Samsung Phone, Verizon Tablet, and Nexus Tablet were plug and play.